# Rails Join and select option with one to many relationship

Tags: activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-4, one-to-many

I have two models User and Profile and User can have many profiles and each profile has  a video link.

I want to write an efficient query to find the list of all users( who has created their profile) along with the link of latest video added into their latest profile.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this:

```
User.joins(:profile).pluck(:user_attribute, :profile_video_url)
```

modify it as required -> [Join Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

use pluck! -> [Pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)